# training of hidden layers does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I just got into machine learning and specifically deep learning by myself since one month and working hard on it.
After learning all the mathematical concept, I decided to do it by myself in python with one neural, which is working properly. (super accuracy)

I now decided to do it with one hidden layer of 2 neurals, 1 output neural, and 2 inputs, but this is not working ... Indeed the cost does not decrease and the accuracy does not increase. But the program works (output below)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def init_variables():
    """
        Init model variables (weights, biais)
    """
    weights_11 = np.random.normal(size=2)
    weights_12 = np.random.normal(size=2)
    weight_ouput = np.random.normal(size=2)
    bias_11 = 0
    bias_12 = 0
    bias_output = 0
    return weights_11, weights_12, weight_ouput, bias_11, bias_12, bias_output

def get_dataset():
    """
        Method used to generate the dataset
    """
    #Number of rows per class
    row_per_class = 100
    #generate rows
    sick_people =  (np.random.randn(row_per_class,2)) + np.array([-2,-2])
    sick_people2 =  (np.random.randn(row_per_class,2)) + np.array([2,2])
    healthy_people = (np.random.randn(row_per_class,2)) + np.array([-2,2])
    healthy_people2 =  (np.random.randn(row_per_class,2)) + np.array([2,-2])

    features = np.vstack([sick_people,sick_people2, healthy_people, healthy_people2])
    targets = np.concatenate((np.zeros(row_per_class*2), np.zeros(row_per_class*2)+1))

    #plt.scatter(features[:,0], features[:,1], c=targets, cmap = plt.cm.Spectral)
    #plt.show()

    return features, targets

def pre_activation(features, weights, bias):
    """
        compute pre activation of the neural
    """
    return np.dot(features, weights) + bias

def activation(z):
    """
        compute the activation (sigmoide)
    """
    return 1 / ( 1 + np.exp(-z) )

def derivative_activation(z):
    """
        compute the derivative of the activation (derivative of sigmoide)
    """
    return activation(z) * (1 - activation(z))


def cost(predictions, targets):
    """
        make the difference between predictions and results
    """
    return np.mean((predictions - targets)**2)

def predict_hidden_layer(features, weights_11, weights_12, bias_11, bias_12):
    """
        This function is not generic at all and aims to understand how is made the input for the next ouput neural
    """
    predictions_11 = activation(pre_activation(features, weights_11, bias_11))
    predictions_12 = activation(pre_activation(features, weights_12, bias_12))
    layer1_result = np.stack((predictions_11, predictions_12), axis=-1)
    return layer1_result

def predict_output_neural(features, weights_11, weights_12, weight_ouput, bias_11, bias_12, bias_output):
    """
        Determine the prediction of the output
    """
    layer1_result = predict_hidden_layer(features, weights_11, weights_12, bias_11, bias_12)
    output_result = activation(pre_activation(layer1_result, weight_ouput, bias_output))
    return layer1_result, output_result


def train_multiple_neurals(features, targets, weights_11, weights_12, weight_ouput, bias_11, bias_12, bias_output):
    """
        function of training multiple neural (ajust weights and bias in function of features and targets)
        This function is not generic or optimized and aims to understand better how it works
    """
    epochs = 100
    learning_rate = 0.1

    #display Accuracy before the training
    layer1, prediction = predict_output_neural(features, weights_11, weights_12, weight_ouput, bias_11, bias_12, bias_output)
    predictions = np.around(prediction)
    print ("Accuracy", np.mean(predictions == targets))

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        layer1, predictions = predict_output_neural(features, weights_11, weights_12, weight_ouput, bias_11, bias_12, bias_output)
        if epoch % 10 == 0:
            layer1, predictions = predict_output_neural(features, weights_11, weights_12, weight_ouput, bias_11, bias_12, bias_output)
            print (cost(predictions, targets))
        """
            There are a lot of things to do here !
            to do the back propagation, we will first train the ouput neural
        """
        #Init gradient
        weights_gradient_output = np.zeros(weight_ouput.shape)
        bias_gradient_output = 0
        #Go throught each row
        for neural_input, target, prediction in zip(layer1, targets, predictions):
            #compute pre activation
            z = pre_activation(neural_input, weight_ouput, bias_output)
            #Update the gradient
            weights_gradient_output += (prediction - target)* derivative_activation(prediction) * neural_input
            bias_gradient_output += (prediction - target)* derivative_activation(prediction)

        """
            Now we are going to train hiddens layer of neurals
        """
        weights_gradient_11 = np.zeros(weights_11.shape)
        bias_gradient_11 = 0

        weights_gradient_12 = np.zeros(weights_12.shape)
        bias_gradient_12 = 0

        #Go throught each row
        for neural_output, feature, target, prediction in zip(layer1, features, targets, predictions):
            #compute pre activation
            z = pre_activation(neural_input, weights_11, bias_11)
            #Update the gradient
            weights_gradient_11 += (prediction - target)* derivative_activation(prediction) * weight_ouput[0]  * derivative_activation(neural_output[0]) * feature
            bias_gradient_11 += (prediction - target)* derivative_activation(prediction) * weight_ouput[0]  * derivative_activation(neural_output[0])

            #print (weights_gradient_11)
            #Update the gradient
            weights_gradient_12 += (prediction - target)* derivative_activation(prediction) * weight_ouput[1]  * derivative_activation(neural_output[1]) * feature
            bias_gradient_12 += (prediction - target)* derivative_activation(prediction) * weight_ouput[1]  * derivative_activation(neural_output[1])

        #Update the weights and bias
        weight_ouput = weight_ouput - (learning_rate * weights_gradient_output)
        bias_output = bias_output - (learning_rate * bias_gradient_output)
        weights_11 =  weights_11 - (learning_rate * weights_gradient_11)
        bias_11 =  bias_11 - (learning_rate * bias_gradient_11)
        weights_12 =  weights_12 - (learning_rate * weights_gradient_12)
        bias_12 =  bias_12 - (learning_rate * bias_gradient_12)

    layer1, prediction = predict_output_neural(features, weights_11, weights_12, weight_ouput, bias_11, bias_12, bias_output)
    predictions = np.around(prediction)
    print ("Accuracy", np.mean(predictions == targets))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #dataset
    features, targets  = get_dataset()
    #variables
    weights_11, weights_12, weight_ouput, bias_11, bias_12, bias_output = init_variables()
    layer1_result, output_result = predict_output_neural(features, weights_11, weights_12, weight_ouput, bias_11, bias_12, bias_output)
    train_multiple_neurals(features, targets, weights_11, weights_12, weight_ouput, bias_11, bias_12, bias_output)
```

The code is NOT efficient cause I'm trying to do it step by step in order to understand everything, I know the problem is in the training of hiddens layer, but they respect the formulas I've seen on internet (neural input * (prediction - targets) * sigmoid'(prediction) * (weightOfTheNextLayer), that's why I really don't understand.

Here is my output (Accuracy at the end at at the beginning and between its the cost), and the accuracy does not increase and the cost does not decrease:

```
Accuracy 0.6025
0.32149563353794364
0.3216454935878719
0.32177853678600526
0.32189583396850424
0.32199849304998307
0.3220876323586574
0.3221644075538757
0.32223008209366144
0.32228608192864866
0.32233396315649065
0.3223752777740352
0.32241140511378036
0.3224434401200392
0.3224721764785219
0.32249815913581226
0.32252176039218206
0.32254324818743063
0.32256283493698107
0.32258070692435065
0.3225970387325917
0.3226119980415239
0.322625745368742
0.3226384319652169
0.32265019765826863
0.3226611692835548
0.32267145957097
0.3226811659211415
0.32269036836411585
0.3226991261062232
0.32270747252405985
0.3227154094426258
0.3227229031837465
0.32272988687106613
0.3227362744197289
0.3227419889521814
0.3227470002539846
0.32275135531703975
0.3227551824643601
0.3227586613182756
0.32276197240283183
0.32276525289471264
0.32276857750543586
0.3227719648351581
0.3227753969249716
0.32277883940346674
0.3227822558361521
0.32278561551026963
0.3227888964074382
0.322792085387534
0.3227951770494241
Accuracy 0.5
```

If you guys could help me with that, that would be awesome !

Comment: It isn't clear what isn't working see [ask]. What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your derivative function has some error.

```
def derivative_activation(z):
    """
        compute the derivative of the activation (derivative of sigmoide)
    """
    return activation(z) * (1 - activation(z))
```

Let's say you have `out_F = sigmod(in_F)` at your last output layer, where `out_F` is your `prediction` and `in_F` is input to your last node.
Here for this function, as your function name suggests, probably refers to 
taking deravitive to that `in_F`. So it should be `d{out_F}/d{in_F} = out_F * (1 - out_F)`

Try this:

```
def derivative_activation(z):
    """
        compute the derivative of the activation (derivative of sigmoide)
    """
    return z * (1 - z)
```